# Finding points in common

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, tangent-line

So I had these two functions and the following exercise:

> $f(x)=x^3-2x^2$
>
> $g_p(x)=px$
>
> Determine all values of $p$ for which $f$ and $g_p$ have three points in common.

Whats a good way to tackle this? I tried equaling them to each other but that doesn't seem to work. Any good methods? (No hints please).

Answer (score 1):

The method that you mentioned is the way to go:\begin{align}x^3-2x^2=px&\iff x=0\vee x^2-2x=p.\end{align}If $p=0$, then there will be only two points in common ($(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$). So, solve the equation $x^2-2x=p$ assuming that $p\neq0$ and make sure that you get two distinct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, equalling them is the way to go. Then use the fact that

> A polynomial $P$ of degree $3$ has three distinct roots if and only if its
>   derivative $P'$ vanishes in two points $x_1,x_2$ such that $P(x_1)$ and $P(x_2)$ have opposite sign.

The derivative of $P$ here is $3x^2-2x-p$. The quadratic formula tells you what the roots are. Finally, note that $P(x_1)$ and $P(x_2)$ have opposite sign is equivalent to $$P(x_1)P(x_2)<0$$
Therefore all you have to do is solve this inequation for $p$.

---

Edit: @JoséCarlosSantos method is more efficient here since you can factor out an $x$. I'll leave this method though since it may apply in a more general context.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$x^3+2x^2=px$$
We can rearrange this to:
$$x(x^2+2x-p)=0$$
From this we gather $x=0$ is always a solution.

We then need to find the $p$ such that $x^2+2x-p$ has two real solutions.

We use the Discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ for this, since the solutions to $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are found by: $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt D}{2a}$$ and $D$ must be $>0$ for the solutions to be real and distinct. Here $a=1, b=2, c=-p$, and so we get:
$$2^2-4(1)(-p)>0$$
$$\to4+4p>0$$
$$\to p>-1$$